# Viewing relevant information about file accesses from the audit log

Tags: command-line, files, security, logs, audit

Assume, you have a Linux machine and there are three users -

`user1`, `user2` and `user3`, who can log in to the machine.

You created a rule

`$ auditctl -w /etc/file.txt -p rwxa`

If you would like to see daily, who and in what time accessed the
`file.txt` how would you do it to minimize information overload, because you use a few apps that access `file.txt` and create a lot
of logged data. There is a need to see only file accesses to `file.txt` from other users (`user1`, `user2`, `user3`, their apps, remote users, etc.)

Comment: If I was on that system, I would copy the file, so you did not know when I looked at it(s contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are user-space tools for filtering and reporting audit events. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Creating_Audit_Reports.html for some examples.

For your case you could try something like:

```
ausearch --start today --success no --file /etc/file.txt | aureport --file
```

to see all failed access attempts on the file for current day.

Check ausearch and aureport manual pages for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've installed auditd, which seems likely as you've created the rule with auditctl, you could grep by uid.

Find out the uid by using:

```
id user1
id user2
id user3
```

Check the logging selecting the userid in question.

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep uid=1000
```

This is assuming 1000 is the user you wish to see fileaccess for. It will show you, for example, when user 1000 has viewed the audited file.txt, in this case using cat.

> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1484859413.000:83): arch=c000003e syscall=2
>   success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffd50e9eefb a1=0 a2=20000 a3=7ffd50e9c8d0
>   items=1 ppid=28517 pid=28545 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000
>   suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=435
>   comm="cat" exe="/bin/cat" key=(null) type=PATH
>   msg=audit(1484859413.000:83): item=0 name="test.txt" inode=4847
>   dev=08:01 mode=0100644 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL

I hope this was what you were looking for!

Comment: And could you select all the events triggered by other users than user with uid=1000 and root? Usually, there won't be such events. The aim is to filter unauthorized accesses or attempts to access the file (directory).